# create same size of arcs with different labels/text on it

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a circle with same sizes using d3.js but now I want to add different labels to it. Below is my code

```
var data = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];

var r = 200;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(['red', 'green', 'blue']);

var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                .attr('width', 500)
                .attr('height', 500);

var group = canvas.append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(300, 300)');

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r - 30)
        .outerRadius(r);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function (d) { return d });

var arcs = group.selectAll('.arc')
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'arc')
        .on('click', function () {
            console.log(this);
        });

arcs.append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('stroke', '#fff') // <-- THIS
    .attr('stroke-width', '1') // <-- THIS
    .attr('fill', '#dddddd');
    // .attr('fill', function (d) { return color(d.data) });

arcs.append('text')
    .attr('transform', function (d) { return 'translate(' + arc.centroid(d) + ')' })
    .text(function (d) { return d.data });
```

Now I want to add these texts/labels to each arc `12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00, 07:00, 08:00, 09:00, 11:00`. **How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't you simply put the labels in the data?

Comment: If I put labels in the data then arcs wouldn't have same sizes. Here is data array is only used to create same size of arcs.

Comment: You could have either a second array with the labels or use complex data that contains both size and label information.

Comment: Any sample example or could you modify my code a bit?

Comment: There are lots of examples for pie charts with labels, e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1203641

Answer (score 2):

Since your arc sizes really don't depend on the data, you can hard code the value into the pie layout, making all arcs the same size.

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) { return 10; });
```

I also added the `.sort(null)` to prevent the layout from trying to sort the arcs. By default the pie layout tries to sort the arc from biggest to smallest, so if the arcs are going to be the same size it can produce unexpected results.

Now that the data is decoupled from arc size, you can use your labels as the data.

```
var data = ['12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '11:00'];
```

Making those two changes should give you what you want. I put your code with these changes into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shHVx/).

Comment: Thats great it works. Could you also help me out with I want to display these labels at the start of every arc rather than in the middle. How can I do that?